# how to check that all changes were taken after a git merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge-conflict

in our git workflow we use branches (pretty much as described here [a successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/))

so when we merge one branch into the other we use:

```
git checkout <destination>
git merge --no-ff <src>
```

if there is a conflict, after resolving it, i would like to check if the merge was correct (if nothing was overwritten in destination and if all the changes were taken from source).

to check if nothing was overwritten in destination i run a diff between the commit before the merge and the commit with the merge resolution.

but how can i check that everything was taken from master and has not been lost in the merge/resolution?

thanks.

Comment: You should do it manually. Run diff to each file.

Comment: @MegaTron i was afraid of that :)

Comment: I think there is no any way because only you know what changes have to be applied. But may be I'm not right

Comment: sure, i can decide if the result is ok, but basically i would like to do a diff between source and destination, without the extras that have been done in destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can view a diff of the resulting merge with the previous commit in the merged branch

`git diff HEAD^`

this command will show the difference in all files between your current state (which in your case should be the merge) and the previous commit in this branch

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can be certain that everything that is *not* a conflict has been "taken" successfully. And with conflicts, you have to resolve them manually anyways, so `git` cannot help you there.

If you are frequently unsure of what happens during a conflicht, `git help merge` has an option for you:

> ```
>    An alternative style can be used by setting the "merge.conflictstyle" configuration variable to "diff3". In "diff3"
>    style, the above conflict may look like this:
> ```

Setting this option makes it so you not only see your and their side, but also the original text of the conflicting lines. That should remove all guesswork.

Comment: the conflicts are not the problem. but rather i would like to do a diff between source and destination, but without the extras that have been done in destination

Comment: Do you mean `destination` before the merge or after the merge? Maybe update your question above and draw a picture.